# Cannot ping to VMware guest

Tags: ping, vmware-player

I have a VM on my laptop that runs Windows Server 2008.

Both my laptop and my VM are connected to my office domain network, and I use NAT network for my VM.

From my VM, I can ping to my laptop, but from my laptop, I cannot ping to my VM.

I try to ping my VM with its hostname, and my laptop are able to detect the hostname IP, however, it still unable to ping the VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Windows Server 2008 is set to not respond to ping replies.  To enable it;

Go to Window Firewall with Advance Settings from Administrator Tools menu.

Look inside Inbound Rules, scroll down to File and Printer Sharing, right click and enable the one with `Echo Request - ICMPv4-in` rule.

Make sure the icon is green.

Ping your server.

Comment: Hai beano, I try it and still, my laptop cannot ping my vm

Comment: There is another odd thing. The IP segment of my office building is 10.10.20.xxx. My laptop gets the right IP, but my VM gets IP 192.168.23.xxx.

Comment: Ah, you have a NAT'd address on your VM, try changing the network type on the VM to bridged.

Comment: Hey, no problem - glad it works